# How can I change the Chase Payment Iframe html content placeholder?

Tags: html, css, iframe, placeholder, chasepayment

I have an iframe coming from Chase Payment. Chase Payment iFrame has its own placeholder for all element. Is there any way to override placeholders?

What I have now (With CSS):

[image: Iframe coming from Chase Payment]

What I want:

[image: I want something like this]

As you can see on above image, I want to change the `Enter Name` to `Cardholder Name` and `Enter Number` to `Card Number`. Also, on all the select elements, I want placeholder like `Select`, `Month` and `Year`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/xb4hqfjt/) is the Iframe code without CSS where you can see the default placeholders ("enter name", "enter number"...etc)

Comment: You tried changing it using JS?

Comment: No luck, may be doing wrong. Can you give it a try? I have attached jsfiddle code in my question.

Comment: This might not be possible because that iframe belongs to a different domain and it is prevented by browser security.

Comment: Yea. And as far as I know we cannot pass JavaScript file while making an iframe call. So may be not possible!